# Cant compare self because it is nil

Tags: lua, coronasdk

```
local speed=1
  function scrollCity(self,event)
    if self.x<-467 then
        self.x=470
    else
        self.x=self.x-speed

    end
end
```

That's my code and the problem is that it always says for this function that i cant compare nil with number.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the variable `x` (`self.x`) with some number value (`0`?) before calling this function `scrollCity()`.

It is not clear how to do it from this snippet you posted.

Comment: As you can see, scrollCity is just a normal function. He should append that to a table which also holds an x field to make this thing work (calling `mytab:scrollCity(event)`)

Comment: I have no time now, see if you can explain him yourself.